# Does small perturbation in the denominator explode the expectation of a ratio of two random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, taylor-expansion

The puzzling thing I am facing is 
Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $R$ such that $E(X^{-1}R)=1$.
Now let $\tilde{X}=X+\mathcal{E}$ where $\mathcal{E}=X\epsilon$ and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$

By Taylor expansion
$\tilde{X}^{-1}=(X+\mathcal{E})^{-1}=X^{-1}-X^{-2}\mathcal{E}+2X^{-3}\mathcal{E}^2/2!-6X^{-4}\mathcal{E}^3/3!+24X^{-5}\mathcal{E}^4/4!$ ...
$=X^{-1}-X^{-1}\epsilon+X^{-1}\epsilon^2-X^{-1}\epsilon^3+X^{-1}\epsilon^4$ ... using $\mathcal{E}=X\epsilon$.

Now multiplying both side of equality by random variable $R$ and taking expectations we get:
$E(\tilde{X}^{-1}R)=1+E(\epsilon^2)+E(\epsilon^4)+E(\epsilon^6)+E(\epsilon^8)$...

Since every $E(X^{-1}R\epsilon^n)$ can be written as $E(X^{-1}R)E(\epsilon^n)$ by independence assumption and $E(\epsilon^n)=0$ for all odd $n$ and $E(\epsilon^n)=\sigma^n(n-1)(n-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1$ for all even $n$ it can be written:

$E((X+\mathcal{E})^{-1}R)=1+\sigma^2+3\sigma^4+15\sigma^6+105\sigma^8 ...$

And this will eventually diverge no matter how small $\sigma$ one starts with.

So we started with $E(X^{-1}R)=1$ and by introducing a very small perturbation in $X$ arrive at $E(\tilde{X}^{-1}R)=+\infty$ or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Seems ok. Simple example: $R=X=1$, $\frac{R}{X+\epsilon}=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$ is the reciprocal normal without mean and variance...

Comment: In the general case $E(|\widetilde X^{-1}R|)=E(|X^{-1}R|)E(|1+\varepsilon|^{-1})$ and the PDF of $\varepsilon$ is positive at $-1$ hence $E(|1+\varepsilon|^{-1})=+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but without the algebra this seemed so counter-intuitive that I was perplexed. So this problem $E(X^{-1}R)$ came out of a well known economic/finance theory. And the $\mathcal{E}$ I assumed to be a measurement error in $X$. $R$ being observed perfectly. So this result kind of means that there is no hope to empirically check this! I was hoping to test some sample counter part $(\sum R_t/\tilde{X}_t)/T-1=0$